# Airflow is using SequentialExecutor despite setting executor to LocalExecutor in airflow.cfg

Tags: airflow

I'm having trouble getting the LocalExecutor to work.

I created a postgres database called airflow and granted all privileges to the airflow user. Finally I updated my airflow.cfg file:

```
# The executor class that airflow should use. Choices include
# SequentialExecutor, LocalExecutor, CeleryExecutor, DaskExecutor, KubernetesExecutor
executor = LocalExecutor 

# The SqlAlchemy connection string to the metadata database.
# SqlAlchemy supports many different database engine, more information
# their website
sql_alchemy_conn = postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:[MY_PASSWORD]@localhost:5432/airflow
```

Next I ran:

```
airflow initdb
airflow scheduler
airflow webserver
```

I thought it was working, but I noticed my dags were taking a long time to finish. Upon further inspection of my log files, I noticed that they say Airflow is using the SequentialExecutor.

```
INFO - Job 319: Subtask create_task_send_email [2020-01-07 12:00:16,997] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: Could you post your DAG?

Comment: any fix on this? Im having the same trouble